# Как написать выражение компактнее?

Tags: javascript

Как написать выражение "Если строка не равна .zip, .rar и .gzip то ...", не используя

```
if(str!=='.zip'&&str!=='.rar'&&str!=='.gzip') {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С регулярными выражениями и ?/: (не знаю, как называются)) чуть компактнее:

```
/\.zip|\.rar|\.gzip/.test(str) ? alert('Архив') : alert('Не архив');
```

Comment: Да, спасибо получилось еще компактнее

Comment: И ещё меньше:
/^\.(rar|g?zip)$/.test(str) ? alert('Архив') : alert('Не архив');

Answer (score 6):

```
if(['.zip','.rar','.gzip'].indexOf(str) == -1) {
    console.log(false);
}

if(/^\.(g?zip|rar)$/i.test(str) == false) {
    console.log('3');
}
```

Причем первый пример выигрывает по скорости в 2-4 раза.

Comment: Если говорить о скорости, то быстрее всего, наверное, будет

    var formats = {'.zip':true,'.rar':true,'.gzip':true};
    if(formats[str]) {
      // ...
    }